# Associated function `display` is never used

Tags: rust

There is a basic struct implementation that gives me this warning. I want to create methods on a struct. As far as I understand (please correct me if I am wrong), the difference between methods and associative functions is the `&self` parameter. But for some reason, rust is taking those as associative functions:

```rs
struct User {
    name: String,
    date: u64,
}
impl User {
    fn display(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.name);
    }
}
```

Here is the warning which I am getting:

```
associated function `display` is never usedrustc(dead_code)
```

[image]

According to this resource (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html), I think this is the correct way to write methods.

Comment: Methods _are_ associated functions - any and all functions _associated_ with a type are called _associated_ functions. The only difference is that methods take in a `self` receiver, which lets you call methods using the syntax `obj.method()`, rather than having to write `Type::method(obj)` as you would for an arbitrary associated function.

Comment: For the next time, please include the error from `cargo check` and not the IDE.

Comment: These errors are from cargo check, I'm using vscode rust analyzer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods are associated functions, they are associated to the Type. You can even say `var.method()` is just syntax sugar for `Type::method(&var)`, as they do the exact same thing.

Also, while there's nothing wrong with your implementation, for common functions like display, it is more idiomatic to implement the `Display` trait.

```rust
struct User {
    name: String,
    date: u64,
}

use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
impl Display for User {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> { 
        write!(f, "{}", self.name)
    }
}
```

Once this trait is implemented, you can print `User` like this, also you get `to_string()` for free

```rust
let user = User { /* init */ };
println!("{}", user);
let user_s: String = user.to_string();
```

If you want to know more about traits, checkout the [trait section in the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, specially including extra tips! It is a little interesting to see this as the rust compiler has the best error messages so far in my experience.

Comment: @omar In simple cases error messages are pretty good. And in general, still is the most helpful compiler I've ever used. Unfortunately, you will eventually see some really long error messages about `trait bounds were not satisfied` one you start using *generic* and *trait* that are really hard to parse. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73823038/12830907)