# How to idiomatically filter on the uniqueness of an iterable of iterable types in Rust?

Tags: rust, filter, iterator

Let's say I have a vector of vectors `vec_of_vecs = vec![vec![1,2],vec![1,3],vec![2,2],vec![2,3]]`. What would be the idiomatic way of filtering out `vec![2,2]`.

My attempt was this:

```
fn filter_out_duplicates(vec_of_vecs: Vec<Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
  vec_of_vecs
     .into_iter()
     .filter(all_unique)
     .collect()
}

pub fn all_unique<T>(iterable: T) -> bool
where
   T: IntoIterator,
   T::Item: Eq + Hash,
{
   let mut unique = HashSet::new();
   iterable.into_iter().all(|x| unique.insert(x))
}
```

But this gives me an error message I'm having a hard time decoding the error

```
the method `collect` exists for struct `std::iter::Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<std::vec::Vec<u8>>, fn(&std::vec::Vec<u8>) -> bool {all_unique::<&std::vec::Vec<u8>>}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`<fn(&std::vec::Vec<u8>) -> bool {all_unique::<&std::vec::Vec<u8>>} as std::ops::FnOnce<(&std::vec::Vec<u8>,)>>::Output = bool`
which is required by `std::iter::Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<std::vec::Vec<u8>>, fn(&std::vec::Vec<u8>) -> bool {all_unique::<&std::vec::Vec<u8>>}>: std::iter::Iterator`
`fn(&std::vec::Vec<u8>) -> bool {all_unique::<&std::vec::Vec<u8>>}: std::ops::FnMut<(&std::vec::Vec<u8>,)>`
which is required by `std::iter::Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<std::vec::Vec<u8>>, fn(&std::vec::Vec<u8>) -> bool {all_unique::<&std::vec::Vec<u8>>}>: std::iter::Iterator`
`std::iter::Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<std::vec::Vec<u8>>, fn(&std::vec::Vec<u8>) -> bool {all_unique::<&std::vec::Vec<u8>>}>: std::iter::Iterator`
which is required by `&mut std::iter::Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<std::vec::Vec<u8>>, fn(&std::vec::Vec<u8>) -> bool {all_unique::<&std::vec::Vec<u8>>}>: std::iter::Iterator`rustcE0599
filter.rs(15, 1): doesn't satisfy `_: std::iter::Iterator`
```

I believe what it's saying is that the iterator gets consumed in `all_unique` but from what I've read online, it doesn't seem like there's a great way to generalize my `all_unique` function to only consume references.

I could rewrite this using clone but I think there's a more idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: It might be better if you pasted here not the error from the IDE, but the error as it is printed by `cargo check` - it's usually much more readable, especially when it is so long.

Comment: It is better to use `retain()` than `filter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: checkout [this answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73824544/12830907) for why `filter(all_unique)` doesn't work.

---

`all_unique` doesn't need to consume a Vec, `IntoIterator` should be also implemented for the reference.

Here's a working example, the only real difference is instead of `filter(all_unique)`, I used `filter(|v| all_unique(v))`

```rust
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn filter_out_duplicates(vec_of_vecs: Vec<Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
  vec_of_vecs
     .into_iter()
     .filter(|v| all_unique(v))
     .collect()
}

pub fn all_unique<T>(iterable: T) -> bool
where
   T: IntoIterator,
   T::Item: Eq + Hash,
{
   let mut unique = HashSet::new();
   iterable.into_iter().all(|x| unique.insert(x))
}
```

Comment: I thought that `filter(all_unique)` was shorthand for `filter(|x|all_unique(x))` ([looks like I'm not the only one that's made that mistake](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/explanation-for-difference-between-filter-func-and-filter-x-func-x/14945))

In my case is `filter(all_unique)` equivalent to `filter(|v| all_unique(*v))`?

I'd tried changing the signature on all_unique to a reference (iterable: &T) but that threw errors too.

I'm going to have to spend some time on this to understand what's happening and why

Comment: @financial_physician Some of these things are really confusing. I usually split these into multiple `let`s and collect over each step to see at which step does collect stop working and try a different syntax

Comment: Maybe eventually this will make intuitive sense for why the behavior is like this... I might open another question to inquire further. Thanks for providing the solution!