# What is the difference between `filter(func)` and `filter(|x| func(x))`?

Tags: rust, iterator

What is the difference between `filter(|x| func(x))` and `filter(func)`? Perhaps a good place to start would be to understand how `filter(func)` could be written using syntax akin to `filter(|x| func(x))`. My code looks like this:

```
fn filter_out_duplicates(vec_of_vecs: Vec<Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
  vec_of_vecs
     .into_iter()
     .filter(all_unique)
     .collect()
}

pub fn all_unique<T>(iterable: T) -> bool
where
   T: IntoIterator,
   T::Item: Eq + Hash,
{
   let mut unique = HashSet::new();
   iterable.into_iter().all(|x| unique.insert(x))
}
```

```
error[E0599]: the method `collect` exists for struct `Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<Vec<u8>>, fn(&Vec<u8>) -> bool {tmp::all_unique::<&Vec<u8>>}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:44:56
   |
44 |             vec_of_vecs.into_iter().filter(all_unique).collect()
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<Vec<u8>>, fn(&Vec<u8>) -> bool {tmp::all_unique::<&Vec<u8>>}>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
  ::: /.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/adapters/filter.rs:15:1
   |
15 | pub struct Filter<I, P> {
   | ----------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: Iterator`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<fn(&Vec<u8>) -> bool {tmp::all_unique::<&Vec<u8>>} as FnOnce<(&Vec<u8>,)>>::Output = bool`
           which is required by `Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<Vec<u8>>, fn(&Vec<u8>) -> bool {tmp::all_unique::<&Vec<u8>>}>: Iterator`
           `fn(&Vec<u8>) -> bool {tmp::all_unique::<&Vec<u8>>}: FnMut<(&Vec<u8>,)>`
           which is required by `Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<Vec<u8>>, fn(&Vec<u8>) -> bool {tmp::all_unique::<&Vec<u8>>}>: Iterator`
           `Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<Vec<u8>>, fn(&Vec<u8>) -> bool {tmp::all_unique::<&Vec<u8>>}>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&mut Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<Vec<u8>>, fn(&Vec<u8>) -> bool {tmp::all_unique::<&Vec<u8>>}>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&mut Filter<std::vec::IntoIter<Vec<Placement>>, fn(&Vec<Placement>) -> bool {all_unique::<&Vec<Placement>>}>: Iterator`
```

But the code compiles if I use `|x| all_unique(x)`. I know deciphering compiler errors is the recommended way of solving problems in Rust but I find this error pretty impenetrable.

I found a [discussion](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/explanation-for-difference-between-filter-func-and-filter-x-func-x/14945) that seemed to commiserate about the error more than explain coercions but I found [the chapter on coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) in the Rustonomicon too short to provide understanding.

Comment: Thank you. So now I understand that `filter(|x| func(x))` will implicitly dereference x in my case  (it gets transcribed as `filter(|x:&Vec<u8>| func(*x))`) but why does `filter(func)` consume the variable while the former does not? How does `filter(func)` move the values in `vec_of_vecs` from behind the reference and consume them?

Comment: (your comments disappeared but I thought they were insightful haha)

Comment: My comments where incorrect, I played around with your example and it seems to have been caused by something else entirely. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @mousetail See [playgound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3f1efb1c7112cc5427d8bd77378a1eb) for what I believe to be the problem. It seems to be related to lifetime

Comment: @YichyZhang Why would we expect the 2 different syntaxes to change the lifetime?

Comment: Related Q&A: [What's the difference between `.map(f)` and `.map(|x| f(x))`?](/q/67864911/2189130) but the solution there *was* due to type coercion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This case is not related to coercions. This is another case of [late-bound vs. early-bound lifetimes](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/early-late-bound.html).

Rust has two kinds of lifetimes: **early-bound** and **late-bound**. The difference boils down to it is decided what lifetime to use.

For late bound lifetimes, you get a [Higher-Ranked Trait Bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) - something like `for<'a> fn(&'a i32)`. Then, a lifetime is picked only when the function is called.

For early-bound lifetimes, on the other hand, you get `fn(&'some_concrete_lifetime i32)`. The lifetime may be inferred, sometimes omitted, but it's there. And it has to be decided at the time we decide the type for the function pointer/item.

`filter()` expects a HRTB function, that is, with a late bound lifetime. This is because the desugaring for `FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool`, [which is the bound in `filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.64.0/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#899), is `for<'a> FnMut(&'a Self::Item) -> bool`, or, if you wish, `for<'a> FnMut<(&'a Self::Item,), Output = bool>`.

Your `all_unique()`, however, is generic over `T: IntoIterator`. And if we set `T = &'a Vec<u8>`, then `'a` is early bound. This is because lifetimes from generic parameters are always early bound - essentially, because we can't late-bind generic arguments, as there is no way in Rust to express `for<T>`, as generic type parameters are monomorphized and so this is generally impossible.

So, if we reveal the elided lifetimes, you want to satisfy the trait bound `fn(&'some_lifetime Vec<u8>) -> bool: for<'all_lifetimes> FnMut(&'all_lifetimes Vec<u8>) -> bool`, and this bound is false. This is the reason for the error you saw.

If we use a closure, however, we generate a closure that is specific for the type `&'lifetime Vec<u8>`. Since it is not generic over the type, the lifetime can be late bound.

Comment: Great answer to something I'd been wondering for a while. Is there a performance difference between passing a function and a closure that calls the same function? Presumably it's negligible if there is.

Comment: @Holloway There is, if it is not inlined. But it will probably be, and if not the perf impact is likely to be negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. My understanding is `.filter(|f| all_unique(f))` defers the monomorphization of `all_unique`. This allows the compiler to first determine the late-bound lifetime of `f`, and only then should it bother resolving the generic (early-bound) lifetimes of the `all_unique` call.

Comment: @aedm Yes, pretty much that.

Comment: @Holloway I would expect such closures to always be inlined in release builds. Although there is no *guarantee* that such inlining must happen, that kind of optimization is the cornerstone of "zero cost abstractions" and heavily counted on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about what it is happening here. It could even be considered a compiler limitation/bug, depending on your point of view, but I think that this is what happens:

When you write `filter(all_unique)`, being `all_unique` a generic function, it is resolved as taking a reference to the item it is iterating upon, as per the definition of `filter`:

```
fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<Self, P>ⓘ where
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
```

So you are actually calling `all_unique<&Vec<u8>>`. You may think that all is ok, because that `&Vec<u8>` actually implements `IntoIterator` and the other constraints.

But the issue is with lifetimes. See, when in `filter` there is the constraint `P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool` that is actually syntactic sugar for `P: for <'a> FnMut(&'a Self::Item) -> bool`, that is the function must be able to accept any lifetime, and your function cannot.

But, wait! you may say that  your function `all_unique<T>` certainly can take `T: 'a` for any lifetime `'a`. And that is true, but that is not what is happening here: you are calling `filter<P>` with `P=all_unique::<&'f Vec<u8>>` being `'f` that particular lifetime. And that lifetime is not any lifetime! Now your `all_unique` function is tainted with a particular lifetime and it does not satisfy the `for <'a> ...` thing above.

Surely, you do not actually need that `for <`a>` here because you are calling the function with the proper lifetime, but the syntax is what it is and it forces the error.

The obvious solution is to write `all_unique` to take a reference:

```
pub fn all_unique<T>(iterable: &T) -> bool
```

That is actually sintactic sugar for:

```
pub fn all_unique<'a, T>(iterable: &'a T) -> bool
```

where the universality of `'a` (that `for <'a>` thing) is implicit.

And now calling `filter(all_unique)` selects the generic `all_unique::<Vec<u8>>`, that is untainted with lifetimes and *can* be called with any `'a`.

And this is indeed is a syntactic limitation, you can just write:

```
pub fn all_unique<T> (iterable: T) -> bool { /* ... */ }

pub fn all_unique_ref<'a, T> (iterable: &'a T) -> bool {
    all_unique::<&T>(iterable)
}
```

And writing `filter(all_unique_ref)` will work while `filter(all_unique)` will not.

Your solution of using a lambda expression:

```
filter(|x| all_unique(x))
```

is just like that `all_unique_ref` but anonymous.

**TL;DR;** The original error is caused because the lifetime of the argument is captured in the type of the generic function instead of in the *usage* of that function. And that makes `filter()` unhappy because its argument does not look generic enough.

Comment: If I implement `all_unique_ref` that actually breaks the the function because into_iter() wants to consume the `T` and `T` doesn't implement copy